# Re-send a Twilio SMS Message

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I store sent messages in a log table with their unique SIDs. With a periodic console task I iterate over the records having status = `undelivered` and request the status of it and if it's still `undelivered`, I'd like to re-send that very message. I don't want a new one as the message contains a verification code and we store only hash of it. Is it possible to re-send the old message having its SID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

There is not a way to automatically resend an undelivered message using the API. You can work around this by grabbing the messages by SID and sending the undelivered ones again to the same number with the same body. When you use the REST API to get a message by SID, you have access to all of the data from that message, including the exact message body.

A quick example using the Twilio PHP Library would look like this:

```
<?php
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$messageSIDs = array("Insert", "Array of", "Message SIDs", "here");

foreach ($messageSIDs as $sid) {

    $msg = $client->account->messages->get($sid);

    if ($msg->status == "undelivered") {
        echo "Resending undelivered message for SID: $sid\n";
        $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

            // The number we are sending from.
            $msg->from,

            // The number we are sending to.
            $msg->to,

            // The sms body.
            $msg->body
        );
    }
}
```

You can see all of the data that the REST API gives you about messages [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message&utm_campaign=stackathon)

Comment: Yep, thanks, that's what I did today. We also save the number and body in our log. But since all the message details are already fetched along with the status, that's not that important, probably. Thanks anyway, I'll accept the answer.